# How to keep open sub menu when link is hovered?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a nav. menu with `categories`, `subcategories` and it's `subcategories` in jquery. However it is not working. I dont want to dirty here by pasting many html and css codes. I created a jsFiddle which will me more confortable to trace I think.
Here is my jsFiddle : [JSFIDDLE url](http://jsfiddle.net/jd24P/) 
As you can see from my html code, there is 3 menu inside eachother. first if LINK hovered I want categories append and then if one of categories hovered, its subCategories should be showed and so on. Thank you.

Comment: it is still not working. When I hover on opened categories, It slide up again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done with a pure-CSS approach? How about something like this one:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="categories">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Sub-Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#categories ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#categories li:hover > ul {
  height: auto;
}
```

Just improve the CSS to suit your needs, but basically that's the structure.

Comment: Yes you are right. But this does not suit well to my requirement. I can use what you recomend for showing sub menus. But I just need to slide down the main menu when h3 hover and slide it up again just when unhover.

Comment: for sliding it down, I think adding CSS transitions on the submenus works? so as to give a sliding down effect..

Answer (score 0):

try to hide submenu on hover out of menu.

```
$('h3.tumKat').hover(function() {
    $('.menu1ul').slideDown(350);
});

$(".menu1ul").hover(null, function() {

    $('.menu1ul').slideUp(350);;

});
```

does it satisfies you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is working but not properly. Because when I hover h3 and unhover, it is not slidening up.